# get Physical Memory for iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management

I have written the code to get the Physical Memory . Please tell me whether it is correct or not?

```
-(uint64_t)returnPhysicalMemory
{
    uint64_t phy = HW_MEMSIZE;
    NSNumber *bobsNumber=[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLong:phy];

    return phy;
}
```

Comment: Physical memory!!! stands for RAM, Cache memory, Register or HardDisk ?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I have used this command HW_MEMSIZE

Comment: ?So if you have tried it, what was the output on diff devices

Comment: I think StackOverflow is not for this kind of question, You should try here : http://codereview.stackexchange.com/?as=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through the following link.

http://iphonesdkdev.blogspot.in/2009/01/source-code-get-hardware-info-of-iphone.html

Hope it would solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot Addhira +1 and correct answer for you